# Given six vertices, is it possible to express the mutually minimal distance from any point in one 3D triangle to any point in the other?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given six vertices, three describing the first 3D triangle, and three describing a second 3D triangle, is it possible to express the mutually shortest distance from any point in the first triangle to any point in the second triangle? The ideal result would be a heatmap inside one of the triangles that represents the distance from and point in that triangle to the other triangle. A visual representation might look like this image:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14344809/49796815-a2218580-fd35-11e8-9d95-ed7bb65fada0.jpg

I've found numerous methods that find the shortest distance from a point to a 3D triangle, but I have not yet managed to find a method that considers all points within the triangles, simultaneously.

I'd be interested in closed-form or possible numerical approaches to solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit to show my current attempt:

At present, my solution, implemented through python code (sorry, I know this is a maths forum), is to take the implicit form of a first 3D triangle, thereby generating a signed distance field for said triangle. The exact implementation is based on the method proposed by the author of this source: https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions/

I then use subdivision of the second triangle to generate as many points as I like within the second triangle. By passing all of these coordinates to the signed distance field of the first triangle, it returns the distance in each case. I can then repeat the process the other way around to get distances from the second triangle to the first.

Implementing this code is what led me to ask the question "is there a more direct/elegant method using geometry that can be achieved in less of a brute force manner?

Comment: Could you show us your efforts?

Comment: @Cesareo, I have edited the question to describe my attempt thus far. I'm sorry that it describes a computational approach, but this is as far as I have got.

Comment: HINT: If they intersect, any point on their intersection line IL is the locus of all solution points. If not, the extension planes also result in an IL and the nearest points of non-intersecting triangles may need to be examined for a criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Given three points $p_1,p_2,p_3$we can define a triangle as

$$
T_1 =a_1 p_1+b_1 p_2+c_1 p_3 \ \ \text{such that}\ \ \cases{
a_1+b_1+c_1 = 1\\
a_1(1-a_1)\ge 0\\
b_1(1-b_1)\ge 0\\
c_1(1-c_1)\ge 0}
$$

analogously we can define equivalently another triangle

$$
T_2 =a_2 q_1+b_2 q_2+c_2 q_3 \ \ \text{such that}\ \ \cases{
a_2+b_2+c_2 = 1\\
a_2(1-a_2)\ge 0\\
b_2(1-b_2)\ge 0\\
c_2(1-c_2)\ge 0}
$$

now calling the squared distance between $T_1$ and $T_2$ as

$$
\delta = (T_1-T_2)\cdot(T_1-T_2)
$$

we can obtain the minimum of $\delta$ by solving the minimization problem:

$$
\min_{a,b,c}\delta(a,b,c)\ \ \text{s. t.}\  \ \cases{a_1+b_1+c_1 = 1\\
a_1(1-a_1)\ge 0\\
b_1(1-b_1)\ge 0\\
c_1(1-c_1)\ge 0\\
a_2+b_2+c_2 = 1\\
a_2(1-a_2)\ge 0\\
b_2(1-b_2)\ge 0\\
c_2(1-c_2)\ge 0}
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script materializing the procedure

```
SeedRandom[1]

p1 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
p2 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
p3 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
q1 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
q2 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
q3 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3];
gr1 = Graphics3D[Triangle[{p1, p2, p3}]];
gr2 = Graphics3D[Triangle[{q1, q2, q3}]];
Show[gr1, gr2]

T1 = a1 p1 + b1 p2 + c1 p3;
T2 = a2 q1 + b2 q2 + c2 q3;
dist2 = (T1 - T2).(T1 - T2);
restrs = {a1 + b1 + c1 - 1 == 0, a2 + b2 + c2 - 1 == 0, (1 - a1) a1 >= 0, (1 - a2) a2 >= 0, (1 - b1) b1 >= 0, (1 - b2) b2 >= 0, (1 - c1) c1 >= 0, (1 - c2) c2 >= 0};
vars = {a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2};
sol = NMinimize[Join[{dist2}, restrs], vars];
T10 = T1 /. sol[[2]];
T20 = T2 /. sol[[2]];
dist = Sqrt[sol[[1]]];
gr3 = ParametricPlot3D[u T10 + (1 - u) T20, {u, 0, 1}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3]
```

[image]

Attached a script to elaborate a surface of distances associated to each point in $T_1$.

```
points = {};
del = 0.02;

For[a = 0, a <= 1, a += del, 
 For[b = 0, b <= 1, b += del, 
  For[c = 0, c <= 1 - a - b, c += del, 
   If[-del <= a + b + c - 1 <= del, 
    AppendTo[points, a p1 + b p2 + c p3]]]]
]

np = Length[points];

DIST = {};
restrs2 = {a2 + b2 + c2 - 1 == 0, (1 - a2) a2 >= 0, (1 - b2) b2 >= 0, (1 - c2) c2 >= 0};
vars2 = {a2, b2, c2};
For[k = 1, k <= np, k++,
 obj = (points[[k]] - T2).(points[[k]] - T2);
 sol = NMinimize[Join[{obj}, restrs2], vars2];
 AppendTo[DIST, Sqrt[sol[[1]]]]
]

data = Table[Flatten[{Take[points[[k]], {2, 3}], DIST[[k]]}], {k, 1, np}];
ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1, ColorFunction ->"BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

Note that in the command `data = Table[Flatten[{Take[points[[k]], {2, 3}], DIST[[k]]}], {k, 1, np}];` we should use the rotated triangle instead of one of it's projections.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. This is indeed interesting. I have made a further edit to the question to clarify my ultimate goal, which is to create a heatmap of distance within one of the triangles, where the colour represents the minimal distance to the other triangle. Do you think your approach could be extended to produce such a plot?

Comment: Please. See script attached.

Comment: That's really cool, thank you. Looking at your solution led me to think about the following...

Comment: That's really cool, thank you so much. Looking at your solution led me to think about the following... If the solution to the minimum distance from any point in the first triangle to any point in the second is, at most, second order, could the minimum number of points be generated to fit the 2nd order equation for $\delta$? I'm thinking along the lines of how three points uniquely define a circle. Could some larger of points uniquely define the equation for $\delta$ such that the coefficients could be solved for using least squares? Just a thought :-)